# Mortarboard: Isn't "at least" the daily maximum redundant?

Tags: discussion

Nitpicking here:
The Mortarboard badge description says:

`Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.`

Given you *can't* earn more than 200 points, wouldn't it be less confusing to simply say,

"Earn 200 reputation in a single day"

or, "Earn the daily maximum reputation"?

Comment: Take a look at my [rep history](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10945/p%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%87?tab=reputation) for examples of the below in action.  Most I managed in one day was 285 and popped above the 200 a few times after that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually multiple ways to surpass this 200 rep limit, each with different results:

Earning more than 200 rep with **upvotes** and such, you can surpass the 200 rep limit. You will only get a maximum of 200 rep attributed to your overall rep, but if you do donwvote - or get downvoted, you will still be in the green.

Any rep earned through rewards also does not count against the 200 rep limit.

---

Have a look at this question on the SE Meta: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Non-exhaustive quoting of the list from the referred SE Meta question:

> #### You gain reputation when:
>
> - one of your questions is voted *up/useful*: **+5**
> - one of your answers is voted *up/useful*: **+10**
> - one of your answers becomes *accepted*: **+15**
> - you *accept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **+2**
> - a downvote on one of your questions or answers is removed: **+2**
> - you suggest an edit and it is accepted: **+2**
> - you remove a downvote from an answer: **+1**
> - an answer you downvoted is removed: **+1**
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: **+ full bounty amount**
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: **+½ of the bounty amount** (see [bounty FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) for details)
> - you *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
>
> #### You lose reputation when:
>
> - one of your questions or answers is voted *down/not useful*: **−2**
> - a post where you had successfully *suggested an edit* has been *deleted* (reputation page shows the cause as “*removed*”): **−2**
> - the account of *a user who was the final approver of a suggested edit you made* [has been deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413) (reputation page shows the cause as “*User was removed*”): **−2**
> - you vote an answer *down/not useful*: **−1**
> - an upvote on one of your questions is removed: **−5**
> - an upvote on one of your answers is removed: **−10**
> - one of your *accepted* answers loses *accepted* status: **−15**
> - you *unaccept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **−2**
> - you place a bounty on a question: **− full bounty amount**
>
> #### Additionally:
>
> - You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Bounties and the bonuses for accepted answers are counted separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation “lost” from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.
> - Voted-up comments do not affect reputation.

Comment: You might want to specify what the "rewards" are - accepting an answer or having your answer accepted, as well as earning a bounty.

Comment: @HDE226868 good point there, I hope this does the trick

Comment: But do they count towards the Mortarboard badge? I was under the impression only up/downvotes and accepted answers counted. That way, if you earned 201 but lost 4, it would disqualify you.

Comment: Not all of those count for Mortarboard, though.  For example, you can't save up your acceptances and the +2s they give you to "top off" a day when you're near 200 in hopes of getting Mortarboard -- doesn't work.

Comment: I'll update this with a definitive list as soon as I can manage to grab me a break at work

Comment: Take your time, I'm not in any hurry to close this ;-). Anyway, you're the only one who's answered